# PageViewController pass data to child controller

Tags: ios

I have a page view controller with array referencing storyboards ID of controllers, that I want to show inside. How can I pass data from root controller to controllers indside ?

I tried do to like this but it fails

```
func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

    if let index = pages.indexOf(viewController.restorationIdentifier!) {

        if index < pages.count - 1 {
            return viewcontrollerAtIndex(index + 1)
        }

    }

    var objectController = viewcontrollerAtIndex(0) as! HF2Object
    objectController.object = object
    objectController.serverID = serverID
    objectController.imageURLsArray = imageURLsArray


    return nil
}
```

Whole controller code

```
import UIKit

class HF2PageViewController: UIViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource, UIPageViewControllerDelegate {

var pages = ["object", "reviews"]
var pageViewController = UIPageViewController()
var object:String?
var serverID:String?
var imageURLsArray = [String]()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    pageViewController = UIPageViewController(transitionStyle: .Scroll, navigationOrientation: .Horizontal, options: nil)
    pageViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.origin.y + 64, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height - 64)

    addChildViewController(pageViewController)
    self.view.addSubview(pageViewController.view)

    pageViewController.delegate = self
    pageViewController.dataSource = self

    pageViewController.setViewControllers([viewcontrollerAtIndex(0)], direction: .Forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
    pageViewController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)


}

func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

    if let index = pages.indexOf(viewController.restorationIdentifier!) {

        if index < pages.count - 1 {
            return viewcontrollerAtIndex(index + 1)
        }

    }

    var objectController = viewcontrollerAtIndex(0) as! HF2Object
    objectController.object = object
    objectController.serverID = serverID
    objectController.imageURLsArray = imageURLsArray


    return nil
}

func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

    if let index = pages.indexOf(viewController.restorationIdentifier!) {

        if index > 0 {
            return viewcontrollerAtIndex(index - 1)
        }

    }

    return nil
}

func viewcontrollerAtIndex(index: Int) -> UIViewController {
    let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(pages[index])
    return vc!
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `viewcontrollerAtIndex` method you can pass the data to the `vc` instance, that's the `UIViewController` that you arte going to show.

Comment: tried already, like this https://s.mail.ru/BS9X3Be8HV4D/img-2016-02-24-19-56-31.png but HF2Object doesn't receive anything

Comment: There are some errors with your code, you are allocations another ViewController inside the if but returning the previously declared one. Try with this version http://pastebin.com/X07xMbCB. Or you can add "return vc!" inside the if statement